# CSS/HTML Border line on Android browser (google chrome)! On PC everything it's ok

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```html
<body>
    <div class="proba">
        <div class="proba1">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```css
body {
    background: #acacac;
}
.proba1 {
    background: url(http://ljuska.na.rs/fedge2.png) repeat-x;
    height: 100px;
}

.proba {
    background: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/buy0h2mk/

Everything works fine on a PC. But on a mobile (Android Google Chrome) there is a line like a border but it's not a border.

[image: Mobile view]

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008863/css-border-image-with-transparent-image-shows-an-edge-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an unfortunate artifact of anti-aliasing. Notice that there are some zoom levels in which the line does not appear. A workaround is to add `webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to `.proba`.

https://jsfiddle.net/buy0h2mk/2/